# How to use basic authentication with Rest Assured in this situation

Tags: authentication, authorization, rest-assured

I am trying to use authentication with RestAssured.
Here is my code that does not work:

```
public static void authenticate(){

RestAssured.baseURI = "https://randomUrl/login";
RequestSpecification request = RestAssured.given().auth().basic("user@google.com", "password123");
Response response = request.get();
System.out.println(response.asString());}
```

A big reason for which this does not work is that I am missing certain things because when I look at the actual request in Postman, there is more info in the tabs there as follows:

```
Authorization: Basic Auth: 
Username:"client"
Password:"pass"

Headers: 
Authorization: Basic Y2xpZW50OnBhc3N3b3Jk
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Body:
username:"user@google.com"
password:"password123"
grant_type:"password"
```

My question is what are the missing pieces in my code and how do integrate them so that the authorization works?

Answer (score 2):

REST Assured doesn't send the credentials when using basic authentication unless it's challenged by the server. If the server doesn't challenge, it won't send it. If this is the case you can use preemptive basic authentication:

```
RestAssured.given().auth().preemptive().basic("user@google.com", "password123")
```

Comment: Whether I use preemptive or not I get the same error message {"timestamp":"2022-05-06T06:26:28.591+0000","status":401,"error":"Unauthorized","message":"Unauthorized","path":"/login"}

Answer (score 0):

I hope below code can help you to resolve authentication issue
given().relaxedHTTPSValidation().auth().preemptive().basic("username", "token(in base 64 encryption")

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).